# How to make an attribute a list to contain multiple items

Tags: python, class, attributes

Im writing a code making users input movies they like and what genre(s) the movie is.
Every movie should be able to have multiple genres.

Lets say Movie1 = Film("Django Unchained","western",2012,)

And the user wants to input another genre: "action".

It is possible to make 'genre' a **list** and append the input so that print(Movie1.genre) will print: ["western", "action"] ?

(First question here, new to programming, please have mercy)

```
class Film:
def __init__(self, title, genre, year):
    self.title = title
    self.genre = genre   #if I could make this one a list so I could append other items to it
    self.year= year
```

Comment: What's wrong with `self.genres = [genre]`, or `self.generes = genres` where now you accept a list.

Comment: Using dictionary would be easier

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is create a method that will allow users to take inputs of genres and append them to the list that you are talking about. Here's an example:

```
class Film:
    def __init__(self, title, genres):
        self.title = title
        self.genres = genres

    def accept_genre(self, genre):
        self.genres.append(genre)

Movie1 = Film("Taxi Driver", ["Drama"])

print(Movie1.genres) #prints ["Drama"]

Movie1.accept_genre("Crime")

print(Movie1.genres) #prints ["Drama", "Crime"]
```

I tested it, and it works. Let me know if you need more explanation!

Comment: It works with your example, if I put self.genres = [genre]  - thank you so much for taking your valuable time to help, much appreciated!

Comment: How would you go about inserting the list into sqlite database? The code below only works when "list_" is a string (e.g. list_ = "Drama") but it doesn't work if "list_" is a list with brackets.



`list_ = ["Drama", "Crime"]

def addToDB(title):
    with conn:
        c.execute("""UPDATE film SET genre = :genre WHERE title = :title""",
                  {'title': title, 'genre': list_,})

addToDB("Taxi Driver")`

Comment: `list_ = ["Drama", "Crime"]

def addToDB(title):
    with conn:
        c.execute("""UPDATE film SET genre = :genre WHERE title = :title""", {'title': title, 'genre': list_,})

addToDB("Taxi Driver")`